# Float a popover to the left

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a bottom aligned popover, and an element with a width of 100%

```
<input 
data-placement = "bottom"
placeholder = "Stuff goes here" 
title = "Hello!" 
data-content = "Loreum ipsum sit dolor amet"
data-toggle = "popover"
style = "width:100%">
```

(You can view the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/guvdpuqL/2/))

This is using bootstrap Javascript and I have popovers triggered. Now, when I click on this input tag, it is shown below the element but centered. Is there any way I can align the popover to be on the left as opposed to being centered?

Comment: I think your fiddle example link does not work

Comment: Oh, wow I didn't put the correct link. I'll get to that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
.popover {
 left: 0px !important;
}
```

in your css file. It should work, but the arrow isn't align properly yet.

Comment: Well, your answer solves my question. Thanks! But, do you know how to align the arrow properly? That would be a nice bonus for my popover.

Comment: Found [this](http://codingexplained.com/coding/front-end/css/change-bootstrap-popover-position) documentation. add this to your css file`.popover.bottom .arrow{
  left:10% !important;
}`.

Comment: glad I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
.popover {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this does nothing. Have you tested it? This just keeps the popover in the center.